# Looking for books to further my training, mainly Cisco ASA and networks

Tags: puppet, nagios, cisco-asa

Work has offered to order books for me to learn new things so I've been googling a bit and now I figured I'd make use of the massive internet collective for help on what books to order.

So far I've chosen the following books that all relate to my current job details.

- ISBN-13: 978-1597492676 Nagios 3 Enterprise Network Monitoring: Including Plug-Ins and Hardware Devices [Paperback]
- ISBN13: 978-1-4302-3057-1 Pro Puppet
- ISBN 13:9780735627116 Windows Server 2008 Administrator's Pocket Consultant, Second Edition [Updated for R2]

I work mainly with BSD and Linux but I know those by heart so what I really want to learn is the new stuff. Which is Puppet, Nagios (I know the basics of this but need a book to solidify it) and Windows because I can be thrown into Windows missions further down the road.

Also I've offered to learn some Cisco, ASA5510 and 6500 for example, so what books should I order to learn these systems? I am very proficient in terminals and text commands, I just need to learn the syntax of these devices and also basic training for large scaling networks.

A bonus would be some Active Directory and net-snmp (or general snmp) books too, I haven't had time to search for those.

I am of course looking for people who are experienced and have read the books they recommend, if you haven't then don't bother just googling some up and recommending them, I can do that myself. ;)

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation: Ask your company to fund you a [Safari](http://safari.oreilly.com) subscription. It's the best value for your money.

Comment: Well, since nobody replied I went and asked around in #cisco on freenode for example and put this list together. The Ruby Programming Language ISBN-13: 978-0596516178
Nagios 3 Enterprise Network Monitoring: Including Plug-Ins and Hardware Devices ISBN-13: 978-1597492676
Cisco ASA and PIX Firewall Handbook ISBN-13: 978-1-58705-303-0
Cisco Networking Simplified, 2nd Edition ISBN-13: 978-1-58720-199-8
Windows Server 2008 Active Directory Resource Kit ISBN-13: 978-0735625150